# Secret keys in Diffie-Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman

I assume 1 atleast is excluded from the set of possible secret keys, since you can compromise the key just by looking at the equation if it is 1 $g^1 \mod p \equiv g$. In case g is less than $p$ obviously.

What about lower numbers like anything below 100, would it be clever to discard them from the possible keys in case an attacker tries to brute-force the key with $g^{1..p-1} \mod p$?

Comment: What is the probability that those are selected? Could you stop question flooding and start reading the 751 questions?

Comment: Should you also exclude $x = 89771082227896378268$ from your possible keys as well?  After all, the attacker can easily compute $g^{89771082227896378268} \bmod p$, and if we sees that exact value, then he knows the secret.

Comment: @poncho Maybe, I am not sure. That is why I am asking. But I get the feeling it is not

Comment: Personally I prefer the term *private keys* for Diffie-Hellman. Private indicates that the key remains the knowledge of one party. DH key establishment creates a shared secret, from which secret keys can be derived. These keys are not private as they are shared.

Comment: By the way, the NIST documents (SP 800-56A Revision 3) does not exclude 1 from the private key value during key pair generation. Of course, the chance of hitting the value 1 during key pair generation should be negligibly low.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes double thank you :-)